# Observable#take(Long) not returning desired size of items in RxJava

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-android, rx-kotlin

I am using RxJava/Kotlin `Observable#take()` to get first 50 items from the list. But `#take()` operator is not behaving as it should as per Rx docs.

In Rx docs, `#take()` is defined as:

> "Emit only the first n items emitted by an Observable"

[image]

I have a function like this:

As we can see the `pageSize` argument is `50`

[image]

And initial `size` of the `list` is `300`

[image]

After that `#take(50)` is applied to that `Observable` and at next breakpoint I still get the **full size** list `i.e. size = 300`

[image]

But `just for the check`, if something is wrong with the debugger or observable, I tried to take only items whose displayName contains "9", but this time I get the expected result of `smaller list` with `9` in each of their `#displayName field`.

[image]

I believe `RxJava/Kotlin's #take()` operator is not that crazy and it's just me.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think you confuse two different things here `Observable.take()` operator considers emissions of the observable, not the size of the list emitted. So if your `remoteFollowersService.getFollowers()` would emit more than 50 items it would return only first 50 of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`take` behaves correctly as it will give you only 50 `List<FollowersEntry>` "marbles". Based on your screenshots and wording, I guess you wanted 50 `FollowersEntry`. There is a fundamental logical difference between a container of objects and the objects themselves. RxJava sees only an object sequence of type `List<>` but it can't know about the nested objects you intended to work with.

Therefore, you either have to use `it.take(50)` inside `map` (or whatever the Kotlin collections function is) or unroll the sequence of lists into sequence of entries via `flatMapIterable`:

```
getFollowers()
.flatMapIterable(entry -> entry)
.take(50 /* entries this time, not lists */)
```

Comment: I was trying to sleep and same thing hit my mind, I opened laptop and I get this answer, amazing.. thanks :) Mind always finds a create solution after it tries to ask a good question..

Answer (score 3):

Take a good look at the return type of your method - `Single<List<FollowersEntity>>`. The Observable returned from `remoteFollowersService.getFollowers()` is ***not*** an Observable that emits 300 `FollowersEntity` items - it is an Observable that emits a ***single*** item, and that single item is a `List` containing 300 `FollowersEntity` items. In other words you need to call take on the list, not on the observable.

```
    return remoteFollowersService.getFollowers()
        .map { val size = it.size; it } // for debugging
        .map { it.take(pageSize) }
        .map { val size = it.size; it } // for debugging
        .map { it.filter { item -> item.displayName.contains("9") } }
        .single(emptyList())
```